# Split jQuery cycle pager into divs

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a jQuery cycle slider working fine, but the pager I need split into different places. The paging itself works, but the active slide is the same for each div - i.e. for the first slide, the first pager in each div will show as active. I'm having a hard figuring out how to solve this problem!

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is the paging of this site http://www.cote-carmes.com/en-en/rooms.php.

The idea of the markup is as follows:

```
<div id="home-content">
<div class="home-sub first">
   <ul class="slide-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="home-sub">
   <ul class="slide-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="home-sub">
   <ul class="slide-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery I have as follows:

```
$('#home-slider').cycle({
        pager:  '#home-content ul', 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            // return selector string for existing anchor 
            return '#home-content li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
        }

    });
```

Please help!

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I'm finding it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added a website url as an example of what I need - hope this helps

Comment: I think what OP means is that the pager has a prev/next on the hero slideshow, but also has bullets under the text that describes the image... amirite?

Comment: Now I'm struggling with what the cycle plugin means by "pager". The documentation uses the term without defining it. Maybe when I understand that, all will come clear. Can you point me to a suitable page please.

Comment: Hmmm not really. If you see the example link, you see that the pager is split between different divs, which are positioned in different places. My code above is working like this, except that the active class is not being applied correctly, as it is treating each UL as a separate pager rather that seeing them all as one pager.

Comment: Sorry to clarify - I don't mean a next/prev pager, but a pager that shows each slide like this example http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html

Comment: I think I understand "pager" now. Can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the HTML/javascript as far as you have developed it. Pull in the plugin as a "resource" (left hand column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris,

I think I cracked it.

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SbbTN/1/)** based on jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html.

This is what I did:

- Split the pager ul into two separate uls
- Modified the pagerAnchorBuilder option in the `.cycle()` call as below to make only the first link in each ul an active pager.
- Added some css to give the anchor borders in the two uls different colors (just to indicate the different uls) and to give the active pager links a mouseover effect.

Javascript:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'turnDown',
    speed:  'fast',
    timeout: 0,
    pager:  '#nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        var selector = '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ')';//li selector
        var $li = $(selector).filter(function() {
            return $(this).index() == 0;//accept only the first li in its ul
        });
        if( $li.length > 0 ) {
            $li.find('a').addClass('pager');
            return selector + ' a';//anchor selector
        }
    }
});
```

This may not be exactly what you want but it should give you a way ahead.

### EDIT

Starting with your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HFUz/1/), I ended up with this :

```
$('#home-slider').cycle({
    pager: '#home-content',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '#home-content li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
    },
    updateActivePagerLink: function(containerID, idx, cl) {
        $lis = $('#home-content li').removeClass(cl).eq(idx).addClass(cl);
    }
});
```

NOTES :

- In the HTML, `<div class="home-sub">` wrappers removed - unnecessary.
- cycle `pager` option changed from `pager: '#home-content ul'` to `pager: '#home-content'`
- cycle `updateActivePagerLink` option added - to give a custom highlight effect

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2HFUz/2/)**

Comment: Thanks very much for the time you have spent, but you have misunderstood - I have amended your jsfiddle to illustrate my problem (the CSS is messy, but you get the idea). The active slide is mirrored for each list, even though the actual paging works http://jsfiddle.net/2HFUz/1/

Comment: This is a good demonstration of the power of jsFiddle, and someone needs to learn how better to phrase his questions!!! See my edited answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Where did you find info about the updateActivePagerLink option? How do you think I should have phrased my question? I included my full code, and a link to what I was trying to achieve for reference I thought this was pretty clear. But thanks :)

Comment: Chris, a good explanation on how better to phrase your question would probably be a lengthy treatise on the ambiguities of the English language - [Fowler's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fowlers-Modern-English-Usage-Re-Revised/dp/0198610211/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1348635805&sr=1-3) is very good. Neither `jQuery` nor `cycle` were around in Fowler's time - for `updateActivePagerLink` I went [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html). :))